# Why does WriteEntry not work for this EventLog source?

Tags: c#, logging, event-log

I am writing a simple service and logging exceptions and other notable items to the EventLog. Below is the code for the service. Somehow, although I can see the "FDaemon" log, I don't see any events in it. My started and stopped events are nowhere in the log; the log lists 0 events.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;

namespace FDaemon
{
    public class EmailDigester : ServiceBase, IDebuggableService
    {
        private Timer digestTimer;
        private EmailDigesterWorker worker;
        private EventLog eventLog;

        public EmailDigester()
        {
            // fire up the event log
            this.eventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();

            ((ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog)).BeginInit();

            this.eventLog.Source = "EmailDigester";
            this.eventLog.Log = "FDaemon";
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(this.eventLog.Source))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(this.eventLog.Source, this.eventLog.Log);
            }

            this.AutoLog = false;
            this.ServiceName = this.eventLog.Source;

            ((ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog)).EndInit();
        }

        public void DebugStart(string[] args)
        {
            this.OnStart(args);
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            this.worker = new EmailDigesterWorker(1, eventLog);

            // no need to multithread, so use a simple Timer
            // note: do not take more time in the callback delegate than the repetition interval
            if (worker.RunTime.HasValue)
            {
                worker.ServiceStarted = true;
                TimerCallback work = new TimerCallback(this.worker.ExecuteTask);

                TimeSpan daily = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);  // repeat every 24 hrs
                TimeSpan startIn; // how much time till we start timer  
                if (worker.RunTime <= DateTime.Now)
                    startIn = (worker.RunTime.Value.AddDays(1.00) - DateTime.Now); // runTime is earlier than now. we missed, so add a day to runTime
                else
                    startIn = (worker.RunTime.Value - DateTime.Now);

                this.digestTimer = new Timer(work, null, startIn, daily);
            }

            eventLog.WriteEntry("EmailDigester started.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
        }

        public void DebugStop()
        {
            this.OnStop();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            worker.ServiceStarted = false; 
            if (this.digestTimer != null)
            {
                this.digestTimer.Dispose();
            }

            eventLog.WriteEntry("EmailDigester stopped.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: I am assuming that you've stepped through and the `WriteEntry()` function does, in fact, execute.

If your source `"EmailDigester"` is registered with any other `EventLogs` (e.g. Application, Security, etc.), then the messages will appear in that `EventLog` no matter what you do.  In fact, I believe only the first **8 characters** of a source are considered.

You can check this by going to the registry @:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\` and checking each log's sources.

You might also considering changing your source to a random value (that you know won't be registered) and seeing if your logs show up.

Comment: Yes, WriteEntry() does execute. And, no other entry exists in the Registry for EmailDigester, except for the one under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\eventlog\FDaemon. One weird thing I noticed was that, stepping through, that the eventLog.Entries collection actually contains 85 entries, but I don't see them in the Event Viewer?

Comment: Sorry for reviving this old thread, but how the hell can I unregister my source from "Application"? (I can create custom log and source, but it still logs into Application log). Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: @Mitulátbáti have you tried [EventLog.DeleteEventSource("MyEventSource")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k35xza3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?